# use pandas0.23.4 read_csv() read big file (>450M) `memory error` on raspberry pi2B+

Tags: python, pandas, raspberry-pi

I am using `raspberry pi 2 B+` to start my python data course.

I am able to read a `.csv` file(about little **300M**).

But when I try to read **500M+** `.csv` file, I get `memory error`.

I am using:

- pandas 0.23.4
- python 3.5.6

shell

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 import pandas
 pandas.read_csv('ccf_online_stage1_train.csv', nrows=11429827)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 446, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1051, in read
    df = DataFrame(col_dict, columns=columns, index=index)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 348, in __init__
    mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 459, in _init_dict
    return _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 7364, in _arrays_to_mgr
    return create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, arr_names, axes)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4872, in create_block_manager_from_arrays
    blocks = form_blocks(arrays, names, axes)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4918, in form_blocks
    int_blocks = _multi_blockify(items_dict['IntBlock'])
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4995, in _multi_blockify
    values, placement = _stack_arrays(list(tup_block), dtype)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 5037, in _stack_arrays
    stacked = np.empty(shape, dtype=dtype)
MemoryError
```

Comment: I think you are exceeding your memory (check with `htop` or other program). Also, try to use smaller Pandas batches. It might fix your problem.

Comment: right,i have solved this problem.i answer it, just for help others.i just registered an account.sorry,my English is not very good.